# How to make my laptop bootable to windows 8 and ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, installation, dual-boot, grub2, windows-8

I have a Sony Vaio Pro 13, which came pre-installed with Windows 8 and the Vaio Care/Rescue Utility. My goal was to make it dual-bootable to Ubuntu 12.04 as well. As it turns out, the Ubuntu install worked, but it is not bootable, and after a few runs of boot-repair, it does not boot to Windows 8 and I cannot access the recovery partition that is built into the laptop. The only thing I can do is boot from my LiveUSB (with try ubuntu)
The last boot-repair gave me this : http://paste.ubuntu.com/6464375
and after I tried to recover Windows this http://paste.ubuntu.com/6469950

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `boot-repair` did not update GRUB2 correctly. Luckily, there is a very easy fix for this. Here's what you can do:

1. Boot to Ubuntu.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> To start a Terminal emulator.
3. Type `sudo update-grub` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. Once the command is finished, reboot.

You should now see Windows 8 as an option in your boot menu. Good luck and have fun with Ubuntu!

Comment: Unfortunately **incorrect answer**, as Boot-Repair already did an `update-grub` (see `line 931` of Hugo's log http://paste.ubuntu.com/6464375). Line 938 you can see that there is already a `Windows 8 (loader)` entry in the GRUB menu.

Comment: I've had this same problem. `boot-repair` often says it runs `update-grub`, but often that causes problems. Doing it from Ubuntu itself fixes that (I know from experience).

Comment: Never seen any report about such issue :) If you can reproduce, please could you create a bug report [HERE](https://bugs.launchpad.net/boot-repair/+filebug) ? (please indicate the Boot-Repair log, and the output of update-grub)

Answer (score 0):

Run Boot-Repair again, but this time answer `No` to the question `Do you want to activate [Backup and rename Windows EFI files]`. Then reboot, you should be able to access both Windows and Ubuntu via the BIOS (indeed UEFI firmware).